# How do I get an EAR to read a properties file from a WAR?

Tags: wildfly, classloader, war, ear, properties-file

I'm using Wildfly 11 and Java 8.  I'm trying to deploy an EAR file that contains multiple WAR files.  One of my WAR files contains this in its web.xml ...

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>Owasp.CsrfGuard.Config</param-name>
    <param-value>csrfguard.properties</param-value>
</context-param>
```

The file in question is within one of my WARs at

```
myapp.war/WEB-INF/classes/csrfguard.properties
```

When I deploy the WAR by itself, everything deploys fine.  However when I deploy the EAR containing the WAR I get an error complaining about not being able to locate the properties file ...

```
Caused by: java.io.IOException: unable to locate resource - csrfguard.properties
    at org.owasp.csrfguard.CsrfGuardServletContextListener.getResourceStream(CsrfGuardServletContextListener.java:85)
    at org.owasp.csrfguard.CsrfGuardServletContextListener.contextInitialized(CsrfGuardServletContextListener.java:36)
    ... 10 more
```

I sense that there is a class loader issue happening that I'm not figuring out how to work-around.  How do I tell my EAR file where to find the properties file in question?

Comment: I tried with same approach and i am able to load properties files from EAR/WAR/WEB-INF/classes directory. Take a look at https://github.com/abhijithumbe/EAP7-examples/tree/master/sample-ear sample application.

Comment: Thanks but you are able to control how you load the properties file by using "Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(fileName)".  I have no such luxury -- the csrfguard.properties file is loaded by code that I didn't write.  I'm hoping there's a way to configure my EAR/jboss-deployment-structure.xml file to tell the classloader where the file is.

Comment: Is the csrfguard.jar the EAR/lib directory or the WAR file's WEB-INF/lib directory?

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that the wrong class loader is being used to search the classpath for `csrfguard.properties`, which would cause [`getResourceAsStream`](https://github.com/aramrami/OWASP-CSRFGuard/blob/a494d4d/csrfguard/src/main/java/org/owasp/csrfguard/CsrfGuardServletContextListener.java#L118) to fail.  In the *.ear* file, where does the CSRFGuard library get packaged?

You can try using the [`context.getRealPath`](https://github.com/aramrami/OWASP-CSRFGuard/blob/a494d4d/csrfguard/src/main/java/org/owasp/csrfguard/CsrfGuardServletContextListener.java#L122) fallback by switching to a path relative to the *.war* file:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>Owasp.CsrfGuard.Config</param-name>
    <param-value>WEB-INF/classes/csrfguard.properties</param-value>
</context-param>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Fixed it by adding the `csrfguard.jar` inside the `WEB-INF/lib` directory of the WAR file and not the lib directory of the EAR. Added the `csrfguard.properties` file to `WEB-INF/classes` directory and used the following context param in the `web.xml`

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>Owasp.CsrfGuard.Config</param-name>
    <param-value>csrfguard.properties</param-value>
</context-param>
```